# Issues with document syncing between iOS and host computer

Tags: iphone, itunes, folders, applications

I had an app in my iphone which i recorded a meeting, (TSA) it said it was ready to sync to document folder. so I syncd and they all disappeared.

Where is the document folder located?

When itunes deletes from iphone is there any way to find those and restore?

Why did itunes delete apps that were installed?

Comment: We need the name of the third party app as it sounds like it is talking about the documents folder thats customized via the app, or on your computer, which is ~/Documents or C:/Users/username/Documents respectively.

Comment: Are you sure it was deleted, and not moved out of sight? You can find all your files backed up by iTunes under `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup` but it can be quite tricky to find your document there.

Comment: You are clearly asking three questions, under one entry. You should post three separate entries and word things more clearly.

Comment: Are you using iTunes on Mac or iTunes on Windows? We can't help you with the "where is the document folder located" unless we know that important piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

Did you sync with a computer that you don't usually use? If you lost the app, you lost it's Documents directory, and your recording is gone.

Here's what is supposed to happen;

You're supposed to open iTunes and browse to your device. In the list of apps with the iOS Home Screen style view, there is a section at the bottom to select an Application, and manage it's Documents storage folder.

You do not need to sync in order to view up-to-date information in this screen. You are immediately able to save the data out of the app into a location on your computer.

Unfortunately, if you've sync'ed your phone and lost the app you've also lost the data from within it. There is little likelihood for data recovery on a Flash Disk device.

Comment: Your image link is dead — please can you upload it using the official image uploader.

Comment: No, because the image pre-dates StackExchange's built in image uploader, and it wasn't my image. Since it's gone, it's gone. Given what I wrote 6 years ago it seems like it was a very specific annotated image. I can't find a suitable replacement either.

Comment: Yeah I saw this was pre-stack.imgur, and unfortunately it's not on archive.org, was hoping you might have it saved. No worries

Comment: Document management is still available in iTunes. Click the device icon (for me at least it looks like a phone, but may be the icon of your device, iPad for example, etc.) in the top left next to the media type (Music, Ringtones, Books, etc.). Then on the device screen click 'Apps' in the sidebar on the left. Scroll down. The App Documents management section (enabling you to add files from your computer onto the device, and retrieve files from the device to your computer) is still there.